# Contao is redirecting to non existend development subdirectory

Tags: apache, redirect, contao

Im currently trying to move a website to production that has been designed using contao. The website has been developed in a subdirectory of the current website. Now when I change the DocumentRoot to the contao directory the application automatically forwards me to the /development directory which in that situation does not exist anymore.

I did a database dump and searched it for "/development" to find the variable that is storing this information but I didn't find a match. I then did the same with the configuration files but it didn't show up any results too. How is redirecting handeled in contao?

Comment: perhaps in `.htaccess` file (check if there is one in the root folder of your site)?

Comment: I did already Check this but there is no such redirect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like your `pathconfig.php` is wrong. After deploying/moving a Contao installation, you should always execute and log into the Install Tool under `contao/install.php`. This will correct your `pathconfig.php`.

Also make sure the `RewriteBase` in the `.htaccess` is set to the correct value (probably `/` in your case).